# Finding the Probability Density Function for the sum of two random variables

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, density-function

I have the following density function

\begin{equation}
f_{x,y\left(x,y\right)=\:\frac{1}{x}\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:for\:\:0\le y\le x\le 1}
\end{equation}

I need to find the probability density function for 
\begin{equation}
Z = X+Y
\end{equation}

Here is my works so far

\begin{equation}f_{X\left(x\right)=\:\int _0^x\frac{1}{x}dy\:=\:1\:}\\f_{Y\left(y\right)=\:\int _y^1\:\frac{1}{x}dx\:=\:-ln\left(y\right)\:}\\now\\_{Z\left(z\right)=\:\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\:f_Y\left(y\right)f_X\left(z-y\right)dy\:=\:\int _{-\infty \:}^{\infty \:}\:\left[-ln\left(y\right)\right]dy\:}
\end{equation}
Which am stuck now on the limits of integration for the Z pdf. How do I find those please help. Thank you.

Comment: Avoid [cross-posting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/433502/finding-the-probability-density-function-for-the-sum-of-two-random-variables). Decide where you wish to ask.

Comment: Sorry, where is this type of question to properly post?

Comment: It is on topic on both sites, but it is better to stick to any one at a time.